# Breaking a DataFrame based on Specific Column Values

Tags: machine-learning, pandas, dataframe

[image]

Assume I have the following dataframe which has years of experience and salary.

I would like to create a new dataframe from the existing one, only including observations where salary is above 45000. I would like it to include both columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to separate these values out of your pd dataframe is to use pandas indexing. There are many different routes that you could go, for this, I would recommend:

```
new_data = pd.data[data['salary'] >= 45000]
```

Should separate your data out nicely.

You can read further about this [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).